# PHP getting time by time format

Tags: php, date, time, formatting

I have 2 strings:

```
 1. "%Y%d%m-text.TXT"
 2. "20112104-text.TXT"
```

How can I get `"20112104"` using selected format? I can have in the first string format `"%d%d%d"`, and my output should be `"212121"`. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Assuming I understand your question, have you tried actually passing it into `date("%Y%d%m-text.TXT")` ?

Comment: Could you make it more clear? so that you can receive good answers

Comment: Otherwise you will receive questions, assumptions etc with each answer

Comment: Yah, no idea what you asked actually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
$sFile = "%s-text.TXT";
$sFile = sprintf($sFile, date("Ydm"));
```

If not, please add more context.

Comment: I know, but I simply tried to help him with a solution for his problem. %d is used for http://nl2.php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php. And the solution still works, just replace the function.